# How to use volley post request

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-volley

I am going to use volley to get data

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SummaryPhoneActivity.this);
    String url = "https://covid19storageservice.table.core.windows.net/COVID19Survey?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2020-06-30T18:04:08Z&st=2020-03-30T10:04:08Z&spr=https&sig=Ei3Kcr6xT5e7znK4ebwx6%2FVS09Ia5pbD1lnWRBh6bm4%3D";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response:", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error:", error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I can get error: com.android.volley.ClientError.
Above url is working on postman.
How can I use volley for above case. Thanks for your advance.